# How can I add classes to an item in field.html.twig

Tags: theming

I have a typical content type, with a field, let's say field_name.

I can output each field using the field.html.twig file. In the file, to output each item,
there is a line

`<div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>`

So how can I set item.attributes, to output, say, the machine name of the field, so that my output is:

`<div class="field_name">My Name</div>`

I suspect it has to do with using the:

**function theme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {**

`$item['content']['#item_attributes']['class'][] = $variables['field_name'];`

Is this correct? Where do I go from here? How can I make this work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

*How can I add classes to an item in field.html.twig?*

Use [attributes.addClass()](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates#s-attributesaddclass):

```
<div{{ item.attributes.addClass(field_name|clean_class) }}>{{ item.content }}
```